# How can the Ubuntu phone screenshot sound be turned off?

Tags: sound, ubuntu-touch, screenshot

I have set the phone (Aquaris E4.5) to silent, but taking a screenshot (up and down volume buttons) still produces a sound. How can this sound be turned off? I'm on Ubuntu 15.04 (OTA-10.1).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately it is a [bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/canonical-devices-system-image/+bug/1572058). As an ugly workaround you may press and hold the down volume button until the volume slider goes to zero before taking a screenshot.

Here's another related [bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/canonical-devices-system-image/+bug/1572053).

Comment: Ah, I see. Thanks for that. It's crazy that there isn't a main volume control.